# System bar icons as VectorDrawables

Tags: android, svg, uinavigationbar, android-vectordrawable

I am an LG G3 user and updated my phone to Lollipop. I develop [themes](http://forum.xda-developers.com/lg-g3/themes-apps/theme-lollipop-lollipop-theme-t2944558) for the LG system in order to change the UI design back to stock Android. I am really struggling with the navigation bar because:
- LGSystemUI cannot decompiled recently;
- the navbar icons are defined by vectordrawables within the LGSystemUI.apk.

Can somebody point me to the right direction where I might find the stock Lollipop system bar icons in VectorDrawable format, or at least in SVG format containing the right path information that can be converted into VectorDrawable?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to find these in the Material Design Icons library:

https://github.com/google/material-design-icons

They have started adding vector drawables to it.